# BeautifulSoup4 is not working even though I have successfully installed it using pip Linux Mint Sarah

Tags: python, linux, beautifulsoup

I am a brand new linux user using linux mint sarah and I just installed python 3.5 as well as BeautifulSoup to do some web scraping.

However, when I type in the following command I receive a traceback error:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

The error tells me that there is no module bs4.

I have also tried:
import bs4
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import beautifulsoup

This is weird because if I go into terminal and give the command pip list, it shows me a list of all my programs and it states that I have beautifulsoup4 (4.5.1)

I successfully used pip in the same exact way to install a module called requests and it was successful.

One thing that I think may be getting in the way is that Linux mint comes with python 2.7 installed and my modules are going into a 2.7 folder which seems odd. (However, the requests module that I can successfully use is in the same folder as the BeautifulSoup4 module)

I must admit I have not tried easy_install because it gives me some error about the directory not existing when I try to install BeautifulSoup4 that way.

I'm muddying the waters too much so I will leave it at that. Hopefully, somebody can help me figure out whats going on so that people who have this problem in the future can benefit.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you used `pip3 install beautifulsoup4` and `python3` executable to install and try importing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **BeautifulSoup4** for **Python 3.5**.

**Option 1:**

- Download https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py file to server.
- Run `python3 get-pip.py`
- Run `pip3 install beautifulsoup4`

**Option 2:**

- Download https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4 to server.
- Extract tar.gz: `tar -xvzf beautifulsoup4-4.5.1.tar.gz`
- Go to folder: `cd beautifulsoup4-4.5.1/`
- Install from source: `python3 setup.py install`